# comparing strings inside conditional without declaring them as strings

Tags: c++, string-comparison

the following conditional is clearly False

```
   string e = "English", c = "Chemistry";
   if (e < c) ... // this is False
```

but the following proves to be true regardless of any order:

```
  if("English" < "Chemistry") ...//True

  if("Chemistry" < "English") ... //also True
```

why does it behave like this? I don't understand how the above two conditions can be both true.

Answer (score 0):

It is the value of the pointers that are compared. So it depends on the compiler.

You need to use `strcmp` or the comparison operators for strings.

Answer (score 0):

String literals are just "C-string", that is a pointer to char. Since they are pointers you can use some arithmetic operators on them but if you run your program on different machines, or simply several times, you might get different answers.

If you want to compare two `std::string`, you can use something along those lines:

```
if (std::string("English") < "Chemistry")
```

Note that at least on string must be a `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

`"English"` has type `const char[]`, which decays to type `char const *`: that is, it is effectively a pointer to the memory location where the initial `E` is stored.

When you write

```
string e = "English"
```

you are implicitly calling a *conversion constructor*, defined by type `string`, that takes a `char *` and creates a `string`:

```
string e("English")
```

and at that point, `e < c` is equivalent to `e.operator<(c)`, which actually calls `string.operator<` and performs a string comparison.

But when you compare `"English"` and `"Chemistry"` directly, you do not have any `string` objects, so you're actually just comparing the pointers — the memory locations — and the results are unpredictable. Instead, you need to use the standard `strcmp` function:

```
strcmp("English", "Chemistry") < 0  // false: English is not less than Chemistry
```